AWS Codepipeline with multiple build actions
I have a single repository (myRepo) in AWS CodeCommit that has two branches (main/dev). I have an AWS CodePipeline setup with two Source Actions and two Build Actions. Source Action A is pointed at the main branch and Source Action B is pointed at the dev branch. Also, Build Action A is pointed at the SourceArtifacts of Source Action A (the main branch); the source/build actions for B are pointed to the dev branch. The Pipeline works as expected, however I noticed that when I push a commit to either branch in myRepo it will trigger both Build Actions even though only one of the branches has an update.
Is there a way to limit the Source Actions that run to only the branch the has a code change?

can you share a little bit about codepipeline yml file  ?
